# Is there a circuit breaker extension for wso2 siddhi applications?

Tags: siddhi, circuit-breaker

I was looking for a circuit breaker configuration or a circuit breaker extension to detect failures in my siddhi application, but I was not able to find anything.
Maybe I should implement my own custom circuit breaker pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Siddhi publishes in a non-blocking way. Hence, the threads within Siddhi will not be blocked unless you configure it to back-pressure using  [Siddhi Error handling](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#error-handling). If a connection fails, Siddhi will automatically retry in a back-off retry mechanism.

You can use the [Siddhi Error handling](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#error-handling) to have a handle on the the errors manually. With error handling at Sink, you can handle the error cases using 3 approaches.

1. Log and drop the event
2. Publishing threads wait in back-off and re-trying mode
3. Push the failed events to a dedicated stream and use the events thereafter as per your requirement.

I also believe, it will be more convenient for the users, if this support is provided natively. Hence, I created an [issue](https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi/issues/1556) to raise a feature request.